# Getting the value of a dropdownlist asp.net using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I keep getting an error on this saying its undefined or its null.
How do I get the drop down lists value?

So far I have:

```
this._ddlName = $("[id$=ddlName]"), elm);
var split = this._ddlName.value.split('-')[0];
```

The top line of code is working since I'm using it elsewhere to do something else. But the bottom one throws the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: you are missing `()`. Use like `var split = this._ddlName.value().split('-')[0];'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `()`

To get value

```
$('#dropDownId').val();
```

To get the currently selected text:

```
$('#dropDownId :selected').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using JQuery:

To get the selected value

```
$("#id").val();
```